# Problem with mapnik

Tags: python, mapnik

My code:

```
  import mapnik

geometries = [
    (0, "POLYGON ((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))"),
    (1, "POLYGON((1 5, 4 5, 4 6, 1 6, 1 5))")
]

ds = mapnik.MemoryDatasource()

ctx = mapnik.Context()

for id, wkt in geometries:
    f = mapnik.Feature(ctx, id)
    f.add_geometries_from_wkt(wkt)
    ds.add_feature(f)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ss.py", line 14, in <module>
    f.add_geometries_from_wkt(wkt)
AttributeError: 'Feature' object has no attribute 'add_geometries_from_wkt'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add a link to that part of Mapnik documentation that feels relevant to you.

Comment: wat??i don't understand

Comment: A link to Mapnik API document for making is easier for folks who may try to help you. Is this correct http://mapnik.org/docs/v2.2.0/api/python/mapnik._mapnik.Feature-class.html#add_geometries_from_wkt. And/or link to some usage example https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MemoryDatasource.

Comment: I recommend reviewing this from the site's Help: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange